# Difference between __openat and openat (Android)

Tags: android, gdb

While reverse engineering an Android process, I wanted to explore the openat function. I noticed that there is a symbol "openat" and another symbol "__openat". What is the difference between these two?

Furthermore, if I use `info function openat`, I can see more openat related symbols. Can someone also explain what are the differences between these?

```
__dl___openat_2
__dl___openat
__openat_2@plt
openat
openat64
__openat_2
__openat
__openat_2@plt
__openat_2@plt
openattr
__openat_2@plt
sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.openatSupported
openat@plt
Java_sun_nio_fs_UnixNativeDispatcher_openat0
__openat_2@plt
```

**UPDATE**

Suppose I want to get a function pointer to openat, I can do this inside Android Studio

```
    int (*getptr)(int, const char*, int, ...);
    getptr = openat;
```

However, I cannot do it for __openat since this function does not seem to exist.

At least this is one difference between the two that I know.

Comment: isn't this [libc file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/8b6fea5/libc/bionic/openat.c) the source code for it?

Comment: Hi @mimak

Thanks for pointing that out. That leads me to another observation (I added as an update to the post).